# Converting a basic disk to a dynamic one

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

What does this mean, and how can I fix it?

> Disk Management:
>    The operation you selected will convert the selected basic disk(s) to
>    dynamic disk(s). If you convert the disk(s) dynamic, you will not be
>    able to start installed operating systems from any volume on the disk(s)
>    (except the current boot volume)are you sure you want to continue? (Yes) (No)

What does this mean? Is it okay to go ahead and say Yes, or will something break if I do?

My computer is a Dell and the hard disk is an SSD Fix.

Comment: It's not a duplicate.  The original question in version #1 is asking if there's another way for the questioner to do what xe wants to do.  Of course, [xe _hasn't told the world_ what xe wants to do in the first place, or what xe did to receive this message from the computer](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/problem-report-standard-litany.html). And the non-clairvoyant people who kindly turned the question into coherent English left out that bit, probably without realizing.

Comment: Maybe you should tell us what you are doing -- what is "the operation you selected"?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you absolutely need it say **NO**.
If you don't understand it **definitely say no**

Google it and you will find dozens of articles covering what it is.